# does Express uses cluster by default?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to use `JMeter` running benchmark on pure `node.js` and `express server.`

And the result is :

```
node.js  = 600 RPS, express = 1200 RPS
```

while running benchmark, node.js server always use 1 cpu, but express server uses all.

Does this means that express server uses cluster by default ?

**UPDATE : benchmark code**

node.js

```
var http = require('http');

var Server = http.createServer(function(req, res){        
    res.write('I heard you !');
    res.end();    
}).listen(8000);
```

Express (3.8)

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// ----------- middleware -------------
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname+'/files'));
});

// ----------- route-------------
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('I heard you!')
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: no, it doesn't. you are comparing different things, most likely.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for both cases?

Answer (score -1):

*Express.js does not use cluster.*

The reason you see more cores than a single being busy is very likely due to the node.js with express more efficiently offloading operations to other workers through async code.

You can use cluster with an express, but as long as you are not having scaling issues that is just unnecessary hassle.

Below is an example code [(source)](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/):

```
// Include the cluster module
var cluster = require('cluster');

// Code to run if we're in the master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {

    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

// Code to run if we're in a worker process
} else {

    // Include Express
    var express = require('express');

    // Create a new Express application
    var app = express();

    // Add a basic route – index page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    // Bind to a port
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log('Application running!');

}
```